# How can I refresh my app data regularly before iOS 7?

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications, push-notification, background-fetch

My iOS app needs to refresh data regularly from server, even when the user doesn't start the app.
With iOS7, I can use the background mode 'fetch' to refresh data regularly;
How can I do this in iOS versions prior to 7?

Specifically, can I use local or remote notification to 'wake up' the app to run a snippet of code, without actually sending notification to the user?

Comment: I dont know why an app should receive data while it is not running. Because it can't show oder edit this data there is no need to get it. This will only rape my batterie power. So please load the data when it is needed on app start and not earlier.

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff I need to set local notifications for the user (with the user's consent), and these notifications can change (time/content), so I need to keep sync with server, even when user doesn't start the app.

Comment: It is possible to create local notifications while the app is not running? That's a new feature for me.

Comment: probably you should set remainders and alarms using apple's EventKit. Hope it helps!!